# Get latest order updates Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to create a copy trader which will copy all trades from a main account to child account.

I checked Binance API docs but couldn't figure out much from it.

For example, I need to listen to all order updates such as executed, canceled, placed and so on - what would be the proper way to do that? If someone could give me an example I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at `GET /api/v3/allOrders` ?

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#all-orders-user_data

It returns all open, cancelled and filled orders for a trading pair. If you use the library python-binance, you can easily call it with :

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(...) # your API keys

orders = client.get_all_orders(symbol='BNBETH')

print(orders)
```

But you need to provide a trading pair each time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to create a copy trader which will listen to order events such as new order, canceled, and so on - so that I can replicate these actions on other accounts...